# Swift - Reverting x positions after an animation

Tags: swift, animation, view, uiview, uikit

I have a basic animation working just fine. The only problem is that if this animation is triggered again, the x values of the two circles I'm animation do not return to normal, therefore messing the with animation. I at first thought this would be solved simply by capturing the original X values and putting the circles back to those original X positions, so that the animation could occur over and over again, but when I use the completion, after the first animation, the circles just do not move. Without the completion, they continue moving until they're off the screen.

```
func load() {
    let originalTealX = tealBubble.layer.position.x
    let originalGreenX = greenBubble.layer.position.x

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
      [greenBubble, tealBubble, size] in
      tealBubble.layer.position.x -= (UIConstants.spacing * 2 + CGFloat(size))
      greenBubble.layer.position.x += (UIConstants.spacing * 2 + CGFloat(size))
    }, completion: { [greenBubble, tealBubble] _ in
      tealBubble.layer.position.x = originalTealX
      greenBubble.layer.position.x = originalGreenX
      })
    }
```

I hope I'm being stupid and just missing something simple. Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: What is `CGFloat(size)`? `size` should be a `CGSize` which cannot be converted to a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation block will never reach the completion block because you have set the flag `repeat`. The animation just goes on forever.